# Как открыть Activity поверх другого активити?

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть приложения с несколькими экранами и активностями. Как можно сделать так, чтобы открывая активити2 оно не прекращало работу активити1, или же сохраняло состояние активити1, приостанавливало его когда запущена активити2,  а потом из активити2 переключиться обратно в активити1.

Comment: активити, не видимая на экране, переходит в режим паузы и не может выполнять код. Для перехода в режим паузы не требуется никаких других действий, кроме открытия "поверх" ее другой активити. Для подробностей смотрите жизненный цикл активити (activity lifecycle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С настройками по-умолчанию, вторая активити и так открывается поверх первой, ведь если Вы нажмете кнопку back из второй активити – отобразиться первая (это осуществляется с помощью [*activity back stack*](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html)).

Для сохранения состояния активити, Вам необходимо переопределить ее методы `onSaveInstanceState(...)` и (опционально) `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`.

В методе `onSaveInstanceState(...)` Вы сохраняете состояние активити в объект типа `Bundle`, в методе `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` Вы восстанавливаете состояние активити из объекта типа `Bundle`.

Объект типа `Bundle`, сформированный в методе `onSaveInstanceState(...)` также передается в метод `onCreate(...)` активити, поэтому восстанавливать состояние активити можно прямо в методе `onCreate(...)`, а не в `onRestoreInstanceState(...)`.

Comment: Активности переключаются между собой с помощью intent. Подскажите, а можно вызвав активность вернуться с нее к прошлой без intent? Насчет сохранения состояния, я так понимаю нужно сохранить в переменной при паузе объект bundle, а при возврате оттуда его взять и вставить в onRestoreInstanceState?

Comment: Да, можно, просто нажмите кнопку `back`. Сохранять состояние нужно в объект типа `Bundle` в методе `onSaveInstanceState(...)`.